# Forcing SSL and WWW using .htaccess for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have hosted opencart website on subdomain beta.mydomain.com with ssl cirtificate installed.

I want to force https and www . when someone types beta.example.com should take them to https://www.beta.example.com

I tired following .htaccess  entries

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
```

I dont understand whats going wrong here. thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Can you also show `VirtualHost` entries for your subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Well, the domain you're using in your example is not `beta.example.com` it's `example.com` you should change it to the domain you require. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.beta\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.beta.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
```

What do you use the `RewriteBase` for?

I personally like to use the following process:

1. Redirect to www
2. Redirect to https

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

In case you haven't already checked it, [this GitHub Repository](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess) has some useful info on .htaccess.

Comment: not working. its going to webistes page not found page :(

Comment: What is your domain in this case? I do hope you're not copy-pasting without modifying the domain in the instruction. You have to change example.com to your domain name.

Comment: @maaz if you could post the .htaccess file's code regarding this part it would make things much easier.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.beta\.example.com\.com$ [NC]` - You seem to have copied the double `.com` typo from the question. Minor point, but the `NC` flag should be removed from this _negated_ condition. If you separate the www and HTTPS redirects, you should redirect to HTTPS _first_, not the other way round. If you have plans to implement HSTS then it is a requirement to redirect to HTTPS (on the same hostname) first.

Comment: @MrWhite I corrected that error, as for the redirect I personally do it in that particular order because sometimes SSL certificates are emitted only for the www domain, so if I first redirect to a non-www I'm going to get a non-secure error and stop there. That's why I redirect to www first and then to https. If the certificate covers both versions that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update your config.php file in your home directory.

I don't have it in front of me, but you'd want to change your HTTP and HTTPS url to "https://www.beta.example.com".

Answer (score 0):

for htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NS,R,L]
```

alternative htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

for php redirect
Open index.php file
find

```
<?php
```

add after

```
    if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) === 'www.') {
 header('Location: http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 's':'').'://' . substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 exit;
}
```